# How might I change my DirectX project game's display mode from 4:3 to 16:9?

Tags: directx, directx-9

How might I change my project game's display mode from 4:3 to 16:9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class and change the LoadContent method to see this component in action. You just load the associated content, create an instance of HelpScene, and execute the Show method of the HelpScene object:

```
public class HelpScene : GameScene
    {
        public HelpScene(Game game, Texture2D textureBack, Texture2D textureFront)
            : base(game)
        {
            Components.Add(new ImageComponent(game, textureBack,
            ImageComponent.DrawMode.Stretch));
            Components.Add(new ImageComponent(game, textureFront,
            ImageComponent.DrawMode.Center));
        }
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        Services.AddService(typeof(SpriteBatch), spriteBatch);
        // Create the Credits / Instruction scene
        helpBackgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("helpbackground");
        helpForegroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("helpForeground");
        helpScene = new HelpScene(this, helpBackgroundTexture,
        helpForegroundTexture);
        Components.Add(helpScene);
        helpScene.Show();
        activeScene = helpScene;
    }
```